# Is there a way to find if a Style is inside a ResourceDictionary other than manual search?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ResourceDictionary` with many resources and I need to find if it has a style for a specific type.

I know you can search on the `FrameworkElement` and in the `Application.Current` with the `FindResource` method, but I couldn't find a method inside the `ResourceDictionary` itself, or a general static method.

Is there a way to achieve this other than doing it by hand, with code similar to this:

```
private List<Style> stylesForType = new List<Style>();
private void FindResourceForType(ResourceDictionary resources, Type type)
{
     foreach (var resource in resources.Values)
     {
          var style = resource as Style;
          if (style != null && style.TargetType == type)
          {
               stylesForType.Add(style);                    
          }
    }

     foreach (var resourceDictionary in resources.MergedDictionaries)
          FindResourceForType(resourceDictionary, type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find styles targeting a particular type within a resource dictionary using Linq

```
private Style[] FindResourceForType(ResourceDictionary resources, Type type)
{
    return resources.MergedDictionaries.SelectMany(d => FindResourceForType(d, type)).Union(resources.Values.OfType<Style>().Where(s => s.TargetType == type)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for pointing out Linq. My original code does a couple more of things that is why I can't use LINQ. However, dont you need to also check for the styles inside the MergedDictionaries? I am looking for a built in way of achieving this, but using LINQ should be a reasonable option for some cases.

Comment: The merged dictionaries are other ResourceDictionaries. This method is to handle one. The merged dictionaries could each contain their own merged dictionaries, so you would need a recursive algorithm to process them all. The question was simply "I have a ResourceDictionary with many resources and I need to find if it has a style for a specific type."

Comment: What you are saying is true, but a ResourceDictionary, it can have merged Dictionaries inside, I didn't think I needed to clarify that, sorry. If you check my code it is actually a recursive algorithm, where I check inside the MergedDictionaries as well. I thought you had noticed and you were pointing out with your code that I only needed to check on the Values. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Your method is not recursive; it does not call itself. It will only go down one level of resource dictionary.

Comment: My method calls itself, you can notice after the first `foreach` there is another `foreach` for each of the Merged Dictionaries and I call `FindResourceForType`.